# Declare a new variable for each iteration in a for loop

Tags: java, loops, variables, for-loop, variable-declaration

How would I declare a new variable through each iteration of a for loop?

For example:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    int var1 = i; // in the second iteration, I want a variable var2 set to i, etc.
}
```

After the loop is completed, I want 4 variables, named `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, and `var4`, each set to `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`, respectively (when I set `var1` to `i` in the above code, I am essentially setting it to `1` since that is the value of `i` throughout that specific iteration).

Comment: Declarations in Java don't work that way; they _are_ the code, they're not created _by_ the code.

Comment: I see, so would I have to use an array instead?

Comment: You could kind of makeshift this and add them to a list or array.

Comment: This could have been possible with C macros.

Answer (score 3):

use array, list, map or other kind of data structure.

e.g.

```
int[] arr = new int[4];
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {    // well, we usually write in 0-based manner...
    arr[i-1] = i;
}
// if you want to get n-th value, just do   arr[n-1]


List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}
// if you want to get n-th value, just do   list.get(n-1)



Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    map.put(i, i);
}
// if you want to get n-th value, just do   map.get(n)
```

something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Either use four variables or use an `array`. Here is the array alternative:

```
int arr[] = new int[5];
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
   arr[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: I believe OP is asking for any amount of variables. Wouldn't that make a hashmap or list a little bit better?

Comment: @T.Woody of course yes, but OP asked for 4 objects so fixed size array came to my mind.

Comment: OP said "For example" :)