# How to define multiple set using loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, treeset

I want to define thousands of treeset.How can i do this using some kind of loop?I've tried code below but it gives me "Duplicate local variable" error

```
//String names_array[]={jason,jack,katia,michael......}lots of name here
for (int z = 0; z < 2000; z++) {
  String nameofset = namesarray[z];                     
  TreeSet<String> nameofset = new TreeSet();
}
```

Edit:more explanation needed i guess.I want to create differents sets with different name where each name is some string from list such as jason,jack...

Comment: In your code you have two variables with the same name declared `String nameofset` and `TreeSet<String> nameofset`.  I suggest you rename the second variable. Also `String nameofset` appears unused in you code. What I mean is you assign it a value, but there are no references to this variable after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think of a data structure in which you want to store your thousands of treesets. For example a Map:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> namedSets = new HashMap<>();
String[] names = { "jason", "jack", "katia", "michael"};
for(String name : names) {            
    namedSets.put(name , new TreeSet<String>());
}
```

To get a specific set:

```
Set<String> jacksSet = namedSets.get("jack");
```

Comment: What i want is pretty straightforward i guess.I want to create different set(different names) for each name.Like :   Set<String> michael= new TreeSet();   Set<String> jason= new TreeSet(); .....

Comment: You don't want to make your variable names depend on your data. The closest thing is a Map with the name as key and Set as value, see updated answer.

Comment: Are you sure that code works.Because at first line it says" Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Object> to Map<String,Set<String>>"

Comment: Yeah sorry, that should be a HashMap. See updated answer. BTW, what are you going to store IN the sets? Or is that out of scope for this question?

Comment: Your solution is not the exact answer i was looking for but that works.I am going store strings in those sets

Answer (score 0):

You have two variable by the name `nameofset` inside for loop. Make the following change in your code -

```
for(int z=0;z<2000;z++){
   String nameString =namesarray[z];                     
   TreeSet<String> nameofset = new TreeSet();
}
```

Comment: OP wants to create multiple tree sets with different names. So, this will create tree sets with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to separate `TreeSet` Object creation and assigning to variables into two separate steps. In loop, you can only create Objects but don't try to assign to same reference variable again and again - obviously, that is an error. You need an `ArrayList<TreeSet<String>>` to hold these objects. Later, you can assign these objects to whatever references you wish.

Also, its not clear as why you need distinct variable names to begin with when you can access these objects by their indexes from `ArrayList` and assign to whatever references as you wish.

Comment: it is 1000 line program.if you really need explanation for why i need distinct variable names,i can explain but that is gonna be very long comment

Comment: Basically , you are asking to create a new reference variable in each iteration and that is not possible. Closest is Adriaan Koster's solution. Question has been asked before, [Declare a new variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228233/declare-a-new-variable-for-each-iteration-in-a-for-loop?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You have this code:

```
  String nameofset = namesarray[z];                     
  TreeSet<String> nameofset = new TreeSet();
```

You create two variables with the very same name. The definition of the `TreeSet` object throws the exception, since the local variable name was used just above it. You should use different names and I wonder what you will do with the `String` variable, since it is unused in its scope.

Comment: I want to create differents sets with different name where each name is some string from list such as jason,jack...

Comment: You want to use the names from the namesarray (or names_array, this is unclear). Where would you want to store those names? namesarray is an array and not a list. Do you want a TreeSet, containing String objects taken from the array?